# Semantic Issue. Unexpected Token :?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to do some AJAX using jQuery but I seem to be having an issue.

In my Safari inspector, I'm getting `Semantic Issue` and `Unexpected Token :`.

Am I just being stupid? It seems to be happening on my `data:` line of the `$.ajax` function:

```
function storeEmail ()
{
alert('Entered Function');

email = $('#emailField').val();
$('#emailField').hide();

console.log('Yep: '+email);

if(email.indexOf('@'))
{
    $.ajax(function(){
        url: "emailer/storeEmail.ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "email" : email }
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data.resp == "success")
            $('#emailSuccess').show();
        else
        {
            $('#failedText').html('Error: '+data.resp);
            $('#emailFailed').show();
        }
    });
}
else
{
    $('#failedText').html('Error: Email is invalid!');
    $('#emailFailed').show();
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: Tip: You seem to be using `if(email.indexOf('@'))` to check if the string contains a `@` character, but what it actually does is to check that either the string doesn't contain a `@` character, or if it does, that it's not the first character. Use `if(email.indexOf('@') != -1)` to check if the string contains a `@` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be passing a function to `$.ajax()`. I think you meant to pass an object. Remove the `function()` piece and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass a function to $.ajax, you pass a map(JavaScript object)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "emailer/storeEmail.ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "email" : email }
}).done(function(data){
    if(data.resp == "success")
        $('#emailSuccess').show();
    else
    {
        $('#failedText').html('Error: '+data.resp);
        $('#emailFailed').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get the error is this code:

```
function(){
    url: "emailer/storeEmail.ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "email" : email }
}
```

It's an anonymous function, but the content is not code but the contents for an object literal.

As it's interpreted as code, the `url:` becomes a label, and `"emailer/storeEmail.ajax.php"` becomes an expression. After that comes the `,` operator that separates two expressions, so then it expects another expression, but instead comes `type:`. It interprets `type` as a variable, and the `:` token after it is what's unexpeted.

Just remove `function()` to make it an object literal:

```
{
    url: "emailer/storeEmail.ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "email" : email }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think the `type:` label is fine, it's the string `"email"` followed by a `:` that's unexpected.

Comment: @Kolink: No, even without that line you get a syntax error: jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2MWTn/

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't checked myself.