# ajax method and SyntaxError : Unexpected token ":"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm in trouble with a simple script. I need to parse some xml response from a webservice

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function callws() {
        $.ajax(function(){
                type:"GET",
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                dataType:"xml",
                url:"http://thewebservice/service.action?my=parameter",
                timeout:4000,
                async:false,
                success: parseXml,         
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(jqXHR.textStatus);
                    }
                }); // ajax

        function parseXml(xml) {
            $(xml).find("result").each(function(){
                $("#risposta").append($(this).find("row").text() + "<br />");
                });//each
           } //function parse
    } // termine callws
```

I don't understand why nothing work! I've only an error log from Chrome console
SyntaxError : Unexpected token ":" at line 12 (contentType: 'text/xml',)
I try to use other parameters but all the rows below the first (type:"GET") seems wrong...  imho the syntax is ok in all of the script!

Advices?

Vito

Comment: possible duplicate of [Semantic Issue. Unexpected Token :?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435991/semantic-issue-unexpected-token)

Comment: Did you read the manual, I think not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the ajax syntax wrong. The first parameter is a regular ole' object, not a function. Try this:

```
function callws() {
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                dataType:"xml",
                url:"http://thewebservice/service.action?my=parameter",
                timeout:4000,
                async:false,
                success: parseXml,         
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(jqXHR.textStatus);
                    }
                }); // ajax
 // termine callws
```

^ All I did was take out `function()`

Comment: Ops, sorry -.-
really there's a "function" in overquota :)
I need to sleep. Right now!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax(function(){
```

supposed to be

```
$.ajax({
```